# Duvida em relação animate com jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Suponhamos que tenho uma div com visibility hidden, como proceder para quando eu clicar em um botão essa div fique com visibility : visible e segundos depois volte a ficar hidden? não consegui nem ao menos usar o visibility com animate

```
 $("button").click(function(){
    $("div").animate({visibility:'visible'});

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `visibility` não permite animação, ou está visivel ou não está. Mas podes fazer isso com o `opacity`. Nesse caso o melhor é deixares o CSS fazer isso e não o `animate()` do jQuery.

Podes fazer assim:

CSS:

```
#escondida {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}
.mostrar {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$("button").click(function () {
    var $el = $("#escondida");
    $el.addClass('mostrar');
    setTimeout(function () {
        $el.removeClass('mostrar');
    }, 1000);
});
```

#### exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/easdy832/

O código adiciona a classe `mostrar` quando o botão é clicado, ativando a `transition` de 1 segundo via CSS. Ao final de 1 segundo (1000 milisegundos) o JavaScript remove a classe iniciando nova animação via CSS, agora para opacity `0`.

Comment: cara, pelo amor de deus, porque meu addClass não está funcionando, nossa, estou rachando a cabeça ja, ja tentei de tudo e não vai... ja peguei o seu código a cima copiei e colei , fiz outros exemplos, mas não está funcionando, puts q saco...      http://pastebin.com/1fqt8LM7

Comment: @GabrielLongatti mas nesse pastebin não usas o meu código. Onde está o CSS que juntei na resposta? Com ele funciona bem: https://jsbin.com/nupewunebe/edit?html,output